# C#: Parse XML line by line

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to parse an XML Document and convert it to a C# object. I succeeded with a few entries but for others I don't understand why it is not working. Here is the example xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2" xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2">
    <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
    <cbc:CustomizationID>abcd</cbc:CustomizationID>
    <cbc:ProfileID>urn:www.abc.eu:profile:bii05:ver2.0</cbc:ProfileID>
    <cbc:ID>TOSL108</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:IssueDate>2013-06-30</cbc:IssueDate>
    <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode listID="UL122001">38021</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
    <cbc:Note>Ordered in our booth at the convention.</cbc:Note>
    <cbc:TaxPointDate>2013-06-30</cbc:TaxPointDate>
    <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode listID="ISO4217">NOK</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
    <cbc:AccountingCost>Project cost code 123</cbc:AccountingCost>
    <cac:InvoicePeriod>
        <cbc:StartDate>2013-06-01</cbc:StartDate>
        <cbc:EndDate>2013-06-30</cbc:EndDate>
    </cac:InvoicePeriod>
</Invoice>
```

I succeeded at getting all the cbc items but not with cac. Here is the c# code:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(model.XmlDocument);

XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("cac", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2");
mgr.AddNamespace("cbc", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2");
XmlElement docElement = document.DocumentElement;
var a = docElement.SelectSingleNode("cbc:InvoiceTypeCode/@listID", mgr)?.InnerText;
var b = docElement.SelectSingleNode("cbc:TaxCurrencyCode/@listID", mgr)?.InnerText;
var invoice = new Invoice()
{
    UBLVersionId = docElement.SelectSingleNode("cbc:UBLVersionID", mgr)?.InnerText,
    CustomizationID = docElement.SelectSingleNode("cbc:CustomizationID", mgr)?.InnerText,
    ProfileID = docElement.SelectSingleNode("cbc:ProfileID", mgr)?.InnerText,
    InvoiceId = docElement.SelectSingleNode("cbc:InvoiceId", mgr)?.InnerText,
    IssueDate = DateTime.Parse(docElement.SelectSingleNode("cbc:IssueDate", mgr)?.InnerText),
    InvoiceTypeCode = docElement.SelectSingleNode("cbc:InvoiceTypeCode", mgr)?.InnerText,
    InvoiceTypeCode_ListID = docElement.SelectSingleNode("cbc:InvoiceTypeCode/@listID", mgr)?.InnerText,
    TaxPointDate = docElement.SelectSingleNode("cbc:TaxPointDate", mgr)?.InnerText,
    DocumentCurrencyCode = docElement.SelectSingleNode("cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode", mgr)?.InnerText,
    DocumentCurrencyCodeListID = docElement.SelectSingleNode("cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode/@listID", mgr)?.InnerText,
    TaxCurrencyCode = docElement.SelectSingleNode("cbc:TaxCurrencyCode", mgr)?.InnerText,
    TaxCurrencyCodeListID = docElement.SelectSingleNode("cbc:TaxCurrencyCode/@listID", mgr)?.InnerText,
    AccountingCost = docElement.SelectSingleNode("cbc:AccountingCost", mgr)?.InnerText,
    InvoicePeriod = new InvoicePeriod()
    {
        StartDate = DateTime.Parse(docElement.SelectSingleNode("cac:InvoicePeriod/cbc:StartDate", mgr)?.InnerText),
        EndDate = DateTime.Parse(docElement.SelectSingleNode("cac:InvoicePeriod/cbc:EndDate", mgr)?.InnerText)
    }
};
```

1. Why is the InvoicePeriod parsing not working?
2. Is there a more efficient way to parse a document like this?

Comment: Make your life easier by using `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` and deserialize your content.

Comment: Why not to create class with your xml structure and deserialize to it?

Comment: Maybe try to use xsd tool to generate class from xsd schema and then just deserialize xml to object.

Comment: I had the same issue and I solved  creating a copy of xml where I run a fix function that  removes all the namespace from it.then it worked fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your life easier by using `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`. By using this class you'll get a maintenable code. So you will have something like below:

```
Invoice invoice;
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Invoice));
using (var reader = new StringReader(model.XmlDocument))
{
    invoice = (Invoice)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

To avoid an execption `InvalidOperationException` like you said in comment, You need to do this in Visual Studio **Edit** > **Paste Special** > **Paste as XML classes**. So VS will generate for you the correct class structure for **Invoice**.

Comment: Tried to do it but I get an exception which I could not fix: 
System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 41). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: <Invoice xmlns='urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2'> was not expected.

Comment: @Andrew You need to to **Edit** > **Paste special** > **Paste as XML classes** in VS so you will get the correct Invoice class to use for deserialization because it will contains the correct namespaces.

Comment: This is coming through an API request. But I got it working using the XML Serializer.Thanks a lot!

Comment: actually it only worked after pasting XML as classes in VS. The code I posted above is not the entire file and there was a reflection issue when doing it with XML2CSharp.

Answer (score 2):

I created following class using [Xml2CSharp](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) tool.

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Xml2CSharp
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="InvoiceTypeCode", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2")]
    public class InvoiceTypeCode {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="listID")]
        public string ListID { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="DocumentCurrencyCode", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2")]
    public class DocumentCurrencyCode {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="listID")]
        public string ListID { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="InvoicePeriod", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2")]
    public class InvoicePeriod {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="StartDate", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2")]
        public string StartDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="EndDate", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2")]
        public string EndDate { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Invoice", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2")]
    public class Invoice {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="UBLVersionID", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2")]
        public string UBLVersionID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="CustomizationID", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2")]
        public string CustomizationID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="ProfileID", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2")]
        public string ProfileID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="ID", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2")]
        public string ID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="IssueDate", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2")]
        public string IssueDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="InvoiceTypeCode", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2")]
        public InvoiceTypeCode InvoiceTypeCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Note", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2")]
        public string Note { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="TaxPointDate", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2")]
        public string TaxPointDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="DocumentCurrencyCode", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2")]
        public DocumentCurrencyCode DocumentCurrencyCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="AccountingCost", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2")]
        public string AccountingCost { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="InvoicePeriod", Namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2")]
        public InvoicePeriod InvoicePeriod { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xmlns")]
        public string Xmlns { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="cac", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Cac { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="cbc", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Cbc { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="ccts", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Ccts { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="qdt", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Qdt { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="udt", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Udt { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Now can use following code to deserialize to C# object.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Invoice));
using (var stringReader = new StringReader(model.XmlDocument))
{
    Invoice obj = (Invoice)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
}
```

Comment: @GaurangDave you don't need external tool for generating the classes. Visual Studio already have that feature.

Comment: @GaurangDave actually I encountered some problem with this approach. It cannot reflect a class called ID. But after generating this classes in VS, it worked. It might be a special case, I don't know.

Comment: @Andrew that is fine. You got your answer is what important. Cheers :)

Comment: @GaurangDave Thank you a lot as well!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why many users don't use VS feature - **Paste Special**, but you can copy your xml string, then:

> Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML As CLasses

and VS will generate necessary classes for you.

Then you can deserialize your xml string by using **[XMLSerializer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)**:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Invoice));
Invoice invoice = null;
using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xmlString))
{
    invoice = serializer.Deserialize(sr) as Invoice;
}
```

Example: [DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/82VWmm)